# Android Code Does not scan BLE device CC2650

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I am working with the CC2650STK SensorTag.

I have downloaded this open source app from GitHub: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothLeGatt

However, the app does not scan my BLE device and show on the list. If anyone can guide me or help me modify this code so that it can scan for my CC2650STK device.

Your help is appreciated

Comment: Which phone are you using ? Does your phone support BLE ? If so, make sure you have the latest updates for your phone.

Comment: Hi Ihab, I am using Motorola MotoE2(4G-LTE). And yes it has the latest updates. @IhabHajj

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you set the following permissions:

ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

BLUETOOTH

BLUETOOTH_ADMIN

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

Try to use SensorTag App source code provided by TI at https://git.ti.com/sensortag-20-android?OrderOnline=More+Info&TICOM_AUTHLEVEL=3&TICOM_VALIDATE_INPUT=1