# Sparkfun nRF52832 breakout board not connecting to BluetoothLeGatt source code from Android Studio

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to pair my Sparkfun nRF52832 breakout board (programed through Arduino, using this link: [nRF52832 Breakout Board Hookup Guide](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/nrf52832-breakout-board-hookup-guide?_ga=2.38315043.1609873278.1594083469-349112930.1588804514#resources--going-further) with a BLE android app (which I hope to make) so that I can turn on/off the LED on the board (baby steps). Since I am new to Bluetooth LE, I decided to use the BluetoothLeGatt source code on Android Studio. After going through the code, I understand how it works.

[Picture of the BluetoothLeGatt source code sample page (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlGMr.jpg)

I connected my Samsung Galaxy S8+ and installed the BluetoothLeGatt source app to see if it can scan for the nRF52832. At first I got a red text in the logcat which said that I needed to give Coarse location permission, so I did that in the manifest.xml. Then I ran it again, but I still got the same red text in the logcat.

At first I googled the problem and found this [somewhat similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42216472/android-code-does-not-scan-ble-device-cc2650), however, I wasn't able to get a suitable answer. I also tried to see if I could find source code for the nRF connect app, however, that is also not available. So I'm super confused about what I should do to get rid of that and need help.

[manifest.xml file with permissions (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPzJB.jpg)

[Red text in logcat (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhBhX.jpg)

Thank you for taking the time to read my first post! I truly appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: You need to request this permission in runtime. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/34722591/3472904 The following question may helps as well: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33045581/3472904

Comment: Thank you very much @Anor, this helped very much. It works now.

Comment: @Anor I know its stated elsewhere but Id post this as a solution / answer for others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You need to request this permission in runtime.

More info: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html